# Mongoose - Count elements until reaching specific id in collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's take the following query for instance: let count = await Entity.count(query).sort(sort_options);

< query > and < sort_options > can dynamically change its conditions.

Is there any way I can break the count after reaching a specific id ?
I want to count all the elements before reaching a specific element without using .find because it would take too long to execute on a very large amount of data.

---

LATER EDIT - EXAMPLE:

Let's consider a collection called Student which has the following properties: _id, name, age, genre, average_grade
We can filter and sort the students in various ways. Examples:

await Student.find( { age: { $lte : 16 }, genre: "male", average_grade: { $gte: 7.50 }).sort({ age: 1, genre: 1 });

await Student.find( { genre: "female"}).sort({ average_grade: 1 });

await Student.find( { age: 18 }).sort({ genre: 1 });

...

So on. Based on how the end-user chooses to filter and sort the students, the queries will return different documents in different orders. But I always perform them using skip() and limit() to give the results only for the page user asked for, so I'll never have a reference to the entire filtered array. At some point, I need to know what is a given student_id's index in the collection filtered and sorted with those specific rules.

The easy way is to query the collection with the given filters like this:

let id_student_im_looking_for = ObjectId(< id >);

let students = await Student.find(...).sort(...) //querying the collection with the given filters

let index = students.findIndex((student) => { return student._id == id_student_im_looking_for });

The problem is, if the query fetches a very large amount of documents (500k students for example), it will take a very long time to finish.
Count is almost instantaneous because it doesn't fetch the documents in an array, it just iterates through them and increment a count_number.

Therefore, if I could break the count when it reaches a specific student id, it would give me the index of the student I'm looking for with the given set of filter and sort rules.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question or concerns here. The database is going to search for the matching results pretty much the same way whether `.find()` or `.count()` is used. So it's not clear what performance benefit you are expecting there apart from avoiding sending the data back to the client. What is an example of `before reaching a specific element`?  Is that something like `{ _id : { $lt: <value> } }`? What's the goal? 

Also, what is the purpose of the `sort`? `.count()` should just return a single result, so there should be nothing to sort.

Comment: Hello, I just edited the original question. I hope it's more clear now :)

Comment: The additional edit is helpful, thanks. One other question, how did you get the `_id` of 'student that you are looking for'?  Where does it come from?

Comment: The final goal is to notify the front-end clients through websocket about specific events like add/edit/delete, etc. So when some of these events occur, I have the reference of the object that was modified => notify clients through websocket about the change. They need to know the new index in order to shift the page items accordingly. 
I'm close on solving it with a front-end based solution without needing the index from backend, but a query that returns the index in a fast way might still help me in other scenarios :)